# How do I make a custom view stay in the screen

Tags: android

I need to create something similar as shown in the image, Need some help as I've already tried many things and I'm out of ideas. 
Can't post code, sorry about

Image URL:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdJS4.jpg

(1) Initial State
(2) What I want, (even after revealing the recyclerview in the first view, the other views should stay in the screen)
(3) what actually happens

Each view on click expands or reveals a recycler view inside it
On expanding a view it shows a recycler view

Edit:
This is how I tried the layout to look like(code us abstract not exact):

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <CardLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <RecyclerView/>
  </CardLayout>
  <CardLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <RecyclerView/>
  </CardLayout>
  <CardLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <RecyclerView/>
  </CardLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 3rd party library, you can do this with `MultiLevel Expandable RecyclerView`.

Add the following dependency in your `build.gradle` file in your app folder:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.muditsen.multilevelrecyclerview:multilevelview:1.0.0'
}
```

Here is the detail description and documentation: 
https://github.com/muditsen/multilevelrecyclerview

Comment: Great lib, but it doesn't suit for what I want to do, Any way I can still keep those in screen, even if the recycler view pushes them down, I want those views to stay at the bottom and limit the space that recycler view is taking?

Comment: Sorry for literally asking you about the code, Is there any way I can implement something like I've shown in the edited question?